# create login and logout session in php and database

Tags: php, database

I want to create login and logout session

My table in mysql database is looking like this

```
CREATE TABLE members ( 
id int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
username varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
password varchar(20) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) ) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

and **mysql connection named as loginproc.php**

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Include database connection settings
$hostname = 'localhost';        // Your MySQL hostname. Usualy named as 'localhost',                  so you're NOT necessary to change this even this script has already     online on the internet.
$dbname   = 'database'; // Your database name.
$username = 'root';             // Your database username.
$password = '';                 // Your database password. If your database has no         password, leave it empty.

// Let's connect to host
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or DIE('Connection to host is failed,       perhaps the service is down!');
/ Select the database
mysql_select_db($dbname) or DIE('Database name is not available!');


// Retrieve username and password from database according to user's input

$login = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM members WHERE (username = '" .       mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']) . "') and (password = '" .     mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['pass'])) . "')");
$result=mysql_fetch_array($login);
// Check username and password match

 if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
// Set username session variable
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['user'];

// Jump to secured page
 header('Location: securedpage.php');
}
else {
// Jump to login page
header('Location:career.php');
}

?>
```

**Then created securedpage.php**

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Check, if username session is NOT set then this page will jump to login page
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
header('Location: career.php');
}

?>
<html>

<head>
<title>Secured Page</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>This is secured page with session: <b><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></b>
<br>You can put your restricted information here.</p>
<p><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>

</body>

</html>
```

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="loginproc.php" method="post">




               UserName:<input type="text" name="user" >

   <p> &nbsp;</p>
   Password:<input type="password" name="pass"  >
<p>&nbsp;</p>

  <input type="submit"  value="  Login Here  " >
  &nbsp;
  <span class="style30">| New?</span>
  <a href="signup.php"><span class="style32">Start Here</span>

 </form></body></html>
```

**and finally logout page named as logout.php**

```
 <?php

  // Inialize session
  session_start();

// Delete certain session
  unset($_SESSION['username']);
  // Delete all session variables
  // session_destroy();

 // Jump to login page
 header('Location: index.php');

  ?>
```

Now my problem is when i am entering username and password it will stay only at   index.php , it is not going to another page. please see this code and tell me when i am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: The `index.php` code looks fine to me. Is there any other code left in `index.php` that you haven't pasted here? Also this line `/ Select the database` in `loginproc.php` is not commented properly and will be interpreted as a statement.

Comment: If that is your actual code, this line `/ Select the database` has a missing `/` so try changing it to `//Select the database` - This type of PHP comments require 2x `//`

Comment: it is not `$_SESSION['user']` it is `$_SESSION['username']`

Comment: I recommend you make var_dump() on the query that checks for user

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution for your problem. You have to bit modify your code as mentioned below -

```
 <?php
```

// Inialize session

```
   session_start();

//----***Use variabel to capture start time *****------
```

// Check, if username session is NOT set then this page will jump to login page

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
header('Location: career.php');
}

?>

And in logout page add one entry as -

 <?php
```

// Inialize session

```
  session_start();
```

// Delete certain session

```
  unset($_SESSION['username']);


//---****Use end time variable ---------
// Subtract previous start time variable and end time variale
```

// Delete all session variables

// session_destroy();

```
// Jump to login page

  header('Location: index.php');
```

?>

Comment: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in F:\wamp\www\iwebtechnik\loginproc.php on line 24

Comment: Problem is with the query.. its not executing. please share your query

Comment: "SELECT count(*) FROM members WHERE (username = '" .       mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']) . "') and (password = '" .     mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['pass'])) . "')");

Answer (score 2):

Don't use this line

```
 $result=mysql_fetch_array($login);
```

This will fetch the result into $result as an array, and later own you are using mysql_num_rows() function (which is used for resource , i.e in your case  $login)

You the following code

```
        $login = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM members WHERE (username = '" .       mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']) . "') and (password = '" .     mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['pass'])) . "')");

        // Check username and password match

         if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
        // Set username session variable
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['user'];

        // Jump to secured page
         header('Location: securedpage.php');
        }
        else {
        // Jump to login page
        header('Location:career.php');
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem here:

```
$login = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM members WHERE (username = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']) . "') and (password = '" .     mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['pass'])) . "')");
$result=mysql_fetch_array($login);
// Check username and password match

 if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
```

your query will always retrieves 1 row on **mysql_num_rows($result)** because it retrieves the **count** of users with the condition, if no one match the username and password, the query retrieves

```
|count(*)|
+--------+
|0       |
```

and it is 1 row

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

1. [`mysql_num_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) takes `resource` type as parameter.  You are passing the result of [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) which can either be an array or FALSE.
2. You're using deprecated `mysql` extension.  You should be using either [`MySQLi`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) for new code.

To fix the `mysql_num_rows` problem in point 1, use `if (mysql_num_rows($login)) {`:

```
$login = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM members WHERE (username = '" .       mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']) . "') and (password = '" .     mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['pass'])) . "')");
$result=mysql_fetch_array($login);
// Check username and password match

if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
```

Comment: but by doing so it still showing error like mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in F:\wamp\www\iwebtechnik\loginproc.php on line 24

Comment: Thats because your query failed.  Try executing the generated query in MySQL client first.

Answer (score 0):

```
            index.php

            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html >
              <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title></title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
                <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
                <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="img/favicon-32x32.png">
                <style>
                .head{
                margin:auto;
                margin-top: 40px;
                margin-bottom: 40px;
                width: 500px;
                height: 50px;
                text-align:center;
            }
                </style>


              </head>

              <body>


                    <div class="head"><h1> <span class="strong"></span></h1></div>
                <div style="padding:0;" align="center" class="login-page">
                  <img src="img/oms.png"><br><br>
              <div class="form" >


                <form class="login-form" name="frm" action="Logging.php" method="POST">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="usrname"/>
                  <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password"/>
                        <button type="submit" onclick="return logincheck()">login</button>

                  <p class="message"> Forgot Password <a href="forgotpass1.php">Click here</a></p> 
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
                <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

                 <script type="text/javascript">

                function logincheck()
                    {
                    var x = document.frm.usrname.value;
                    var y = document.frm.password.value;
                    if(x =="" || x == null){
                    alert("Enter the Username ");
                    return false;
                    }
                    else if(y=="" || y == null){
                    alert("Enter the Password ");
                    return false;
                    }else{
                    return true;
                    }
                    }




               $('.message a').click(function(){
               $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
            });  
                </script> 




              </body>
                <?php include 'footer1.php';?>
            </html>


            Logging.php

            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html >
              <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title></title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
                <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
                <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="img/favicon-32x32.png">
                <style>
                .head{
                margin:auto;
                margin-top: 40px;
                margin-bottom: 40px;
                width: 500px;
                height: 50px;
                text-align:center;
            }
                </style>


              </head>

              <body>


                    <div class="head"><h1> <span class="strong"></span></h1></div>
                <div style="padding:0;" align="center" class="login-page">
                  <img src="img/oms.png"><br><br>
              <div class="form" >


                <form class="login-form" name="frm" action="Logging.php" method="POST">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="usrname"/>
                  <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password"/>
                        <button type="submit" onclick="return logincheck()">login</button>

                  <p class="message"> Forgot Password <a href="forgotpass1.php">Click here</a></p> 
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
                <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

                 <script type="text/javascript">

                function logincheck()
                    {
                    var x = document.frm.usrname.value;
                    var y = document.frm.password.value;
                    if(x =="" || x == null){
                    alert("Enter the Username ");
                    return false;
                    }
                    else if(y=="" || y == null){
                    alert("Enter the Password ");
                    return false;
                    }else{
                    return true;
                    }
                    }




               $('.message a').click(function(){
               $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
            });  
                </script> 




              </body>
                <?php include 'footer1.php';?>
            </html>

        Logout.php

        <?php

        include 'header.php';
        include 'footer.php';




        session_destroy();

        echo "<script>alert('Successfully Logged Out');window.location.href='index.php'</script>";

        ?>

    forgotpass1.php

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="img/favicon-32x32.png">
        <style>
        .head{
        margin:auto;
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        width: 500px;
        height: 50px;
        text-align:center;
    }
        </style>


      </head>

      <body>


            <div class="head"><h1> <span class="strong"></span></h1></div>
        <div style="padding:0;" align="center" class="login-page">
          <img src="img/oms.png"><br><br>
      <div class="form" >


        <form class="login-form" name="frm" action="validateemail1.php" method="POST">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email"/>
          <table width="100%">
             <tr><td align="left">
                <button type="submit" name="Back" value="Back" onclick="history.go(-1);" >Back</button></td><td>&nbsp </td><td align="left"> <button type="submit" name="submit"  onclick="return logincheck()">Send Email</button></td></tr></table>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
        <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

         <script type="text/javascript">

        function logincheck()
            {

            var y = document.frm.email.value;
             if(y=="" || y == null){
            alert("Enter the Email ");
            return false;
            }else{
            return true;
            }
            }




       $('.message a').click(function(){
       $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
    }); 
        </script> 




      </body>
    </html>
    <?php include 'footer1.php';?>


    validateemail1.php

    <?php 
    include 'dbConfig.php';


    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $email=$_POST['email'];


    $n=0;

                    $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM signup where email ='".$email."'");

                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                    {
                    $db_email=$row['email'];
                    if($db_email==$email)
                    {              
                    $n++;
                    $to=$row['email'];
                    $subject = "Your Password ";
                    $txtn = '<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="1000">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#2ce0e8" style="padding: 7px 0 10px 0;background:#f55322 ">
               <img src="http://saiss.co.in/supreme_oms/img/oms.png" alt="http://saiss.co.in/supreme_oms/index" width="84" height="36" style="display: block;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 20px 0 30px 0"><center>Hi ,'.$row["username"].'<br>
        Your password is: '.$row["password"].'<br> <a href="http://saiss.co.in/supreme_oms/index.php">Click to Login</a></center>
        </td>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#f55322" style="padding: 25px 0px 18px 23px;color: #fff;font-size: 12px;">
                &copy; <?php echo  date("Y"); ?> OMS All RIGHTS RESERVED.
            </td>
            <td align="right">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>';

       $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
          $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
          $headers .= 'From: <OMS>' . "\r\n";


                    mail($to,$subject,$txtn,$headers);
                    echo "<script>alert('We Sent Password To Your Email Address');window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
                    }
                    }
                    if($n==0)
                    {
                    echo "<script>alert('Your email  is Not Matching with our database');window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
                    }
                    }              
    ?>
Logging.php
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbConfig.php';
$logname = $_POST['usrname'];
$logpass = $_POST['password'];

if(isset($_POST['usrname'])) {
    $name = $_POST['usrname'];
}

if(isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $name = $_POST['password'];
}
if($logname != null && trim($logname) !="" && trim($logpass) !="" && $logpass !=null)
{
    $getvalue  ="";
    $sql_query = "Select * from signup where username='".$logname."'and password ='".$logpass."'";
    $changepass="";
    $result_set = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result_set)==0){
        echo "<script>alert('Invalid Username/Password');window.location.href='index.php'</script>";        
    }else{
         while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result_set))
        {
        $getvalue = $row[0];
        $changepass = $row[3];
        }
        $_SESSION["usrnam"] = $getvalue;
        if($changepass=="Y"){
            echo "<script>window.location.href='changepassword.php'</script>";
        }else
        {
        echo "<script>window.location.href='dashboard.php'</script>";
        }
    }

}else{
    echo "<script>alert('Invalid Username/Password');window.location.href='index.php'</script>";        
}
?>
```